# Residual ADF test after Engle-Granger regression

Tags: cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have long run equation regressing imports on income and relative price.
Here is the result from OxMetrics:

[image]

After identifying the residual, I have run an ADF test with five lags as following

[image]

However my professor tells me that we cannot use the usual ADF critical values to decide whether or no the residual is stationary and we have to use MacKinnon's critical values?

Can some one tell me how to interpret and use the Mackinnon critical values? Where can I find them? How to use them?